# Backbone.js Session Implementation Flow

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a simple OAuth verification set up using Backbone, and it's working fairly well. My question is somewhat nitpicky (though... I am also new to Backbone), but I'm hoping to find somebody who might know how to solve this.

I have a Session model which, at initialization, sets a @authenticated value based on the presence of a value in localStorage. There's also a method in here, authenticate(), which checks the @authenticated value for pass/fail. If the value check fails, it uses my router to navigate to the login route. If the value check passes, an optional callback passed in by the user is run.

In my main AppView (the first View run at application start) I run Session.authenticate(), and if it passes, route to "#home" (and my Router handles loading additional Views).

My question is this: as an un-authenticated user, if I type http://url.com/#home into my browser, I am successfully routed to "#login", but if I bring up my DevTools, I can see a request being made for an image in my "HomeView" view. What am I not understanding about how Backbone flows through this process? Shouldn't the route for "#home" not even run until after the application initializes, and therefore not even attempting to load the "HomeView"?

Comment: Let me know if I can drop any code into a Gist to make something more clear.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of templating engine are you using? If your templates are for instance inline, inside the HTML template where your backbone app lives, then I believe any images inside those are rendered when the page loads. I may be wrong. Also, ensure your HomeView is not running by logging something to the console in the view's initialize method.